# OpenMPI: error: ‘MPI’ has not been declared

Tags: c++, openmpi, mpic++

Always get the following errors while running the OpenMPI command "mpicxx hello_cxx.cc -o hello"

```
hello_cxx.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’: 
hello_cxx.cc:25:5: error: ‘MPI’ has not been declared
     MPI::Init();
     ^~~ hello_cxx.cc:26:12: error: ‘MPI’ has not been declared
     rank = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank();
            ^~~ hello_cxx.cc:27:12: error: ‘MPI’ has not been declared
     size = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_size();
            ^~~ hello_cxx.cc:31:5: error: ‘MPI’ has not been declared
     MPI::Finalize();
     ^~~
```

Comment: To help it would really help to see the code of and not only the couple lines that you put up here.

Comment: Also it would help to know what OS, which version of OpenMPI you use.

Comment: I have tried 3 different versions, all are version 2 or later in Ubuntu Kylin 17.04.

Comment: Since it didn't help at all, I tried installing a fresh "Ubuntu GNOM 17.04" OS and "openmpi-2.1.1". But, it didn't help following a regular process of installation and then enabling "--enable-mpi-cxx". So, after installation and enabling "--enable-mpi-cxx" I rebuild it with "sudo make install" command and it worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

Your application is using MPI C++ bindings.
Keep in mind C++ bindings have been removed from the MPI standard.

From an Open MPI point of view, C++ bindings are still here, but they are no more built be default since `Open MPI 2.0.0`.

So if you are using Open MPI 2.0.0 or later, you first need to make sure C++ bindings were built.
If not, you need to rebuild Open MPI, and configure with the `--enable-mpi-cxx` option.

On the long term, you should really move away from MPI C++ bindings.
You can either use plain C bindings, or explore alternate C++ bindings such as the popular `Boost:MPI` library.

Answer (score 0):

I also meet the problem,but I don't have root privileges. 
As the before answer mentioned , Open MPI 2.0.0 has changed the build mode.So you just need to change the grammar.

I meet the error:

error: ‘MPI’ has not been declared

```
mpifile = MPI::FILE_NULL;
```

From the openmp 2.0 api:

http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.0/mpi-20-html/node217.htm#Node217

I find the new error handle is MPI_FILE_NULL.I change it directly in my code and then it works.

The next link is about the Deprecated since MPI-2.2:

http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.2/mpi22-report/node328.htm#Node328